# How do I create an animated gif in Python using Wand?

Tags: python, imagemagick, animated-gif, wand

The instructions are simple enough in the [Wand docs](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/guide/sequence.html) for *reading* a sequenced image (e.g. animated gif, icon file, etc.):

```
>>> from wand.image import Image
>>> with Image(filename='sequence-animation.gif') as image:
...     len(image.sequence)
```

...but I'm not sure how to *create* one.

In Ruby this is easy using **RMagick**, since you have `ImageList`s. (see [my gist](https://gist.github.com/dguzzo/99bbca3df827df475f768383a1b04102) for an example.)

I tried creating an `Image` (as the "container") and instantiating each `SingleImage` with an image path, but I'm pretty sure that's wrong, especially since the constructor documentation for `SingleImage` doesn't look for use by the end-user.

I also tried creating a `wand.sequence.Sequence` and going from that angle, but hit a dead-end as well. I feel very lost.

Comment: my question looks to be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394869/writing-animated-gif-using-wand-and-imagemagick?rq=1

Comment: for those curious, here's what I ended up with (it works as i want it to), thanks to @emcconville's accepted answer below: https://gist.github.com/dguzzo/cecc2ef8b8b520af3dc40e209eadc183

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best examples are located in the unit-tests shipped with the code. [`wand/tests/sequence_test.py`](https://github.com/dahlia/wand/blob/master/tests/sequence_test.py) for example.

For creating an animated gif with wand, remember to load the image into the sequence, and then set the additional delay/optimize handling after all frames are loaded.

```py
from wand.image import Image

with Image() as wand:
    # Add new frames into sequance
    with Image(filename='1.png') as one:
        wand.sequence.append(one)
    with Image(filename='2.png') as two:
        wand.sequence.append(two)
    with Image(filename='3.png') as three:
        wand.sequence.append(three)
    # Create progressive delay for each frame
    for cursor in range(3):
        with wand.sequence[cursor] as frame:
            frame.delay = 10 * (cursor + 1)
    # Set layer type
    wand.type = 'optimize'
    wand.save(filename='animated.gif')
```

[image: output animated.gif]

Comment: cool, thanks @emcconville; I should've looked at those unit tests!

Comment: How to disable the infinite loop? Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on the frame.delay arithmetic? It seems like the delay would grow with each iteration because the cursor grows. Wouldn't you want all delays to be the same (in most cases)?