# Frames not disappearing in python wand

Tags: python, image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, wand

As per hint from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39939780/how-do-i-create-an-animated-gif-in-python-using-wand), I tried to create a gif with 2 dissimilar images as below. It works, but one frame is not disappearing to show another frame. Why would this happen and how to rectify?

```
from wand.image import Image as Image2

with Image2() as wand:
    # Add new frames into sequance
    with Image2(blob=d2) as one:
        wand.sequence.append(one)
    with Image2(blob=d3) as two:
        wand.sequence.append(two)

    # Create progressive delay for each frame
    for cursor in range(2):
        with wand.sequence[cursor] as frame:
            frame.delay = 100
    # Set layer type
    wand.type = 'optimize'
    wand.save(filename='animated.gif')

display(Image('animated.gif'))
```

Current output:
[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**

> ... I got error using that ...

Looks like hardcoded validation values does not allow this technique to be leveraged. This is a bug, and I'll submit a patch upstream.

```patch
@ -2548,7 +2548,7 @@ class BaseImage(Resource):
         .. versionadded:: 0.4.3

         """
-        if method not in ['merge', 'flatten', 'mosaic']:
+        if method not in IMAGE_LAYER_METHOD:
             raise TypeError('method must be one of: merge, flatten, mosaic')
```

Currently, [wand](/questions/tagged/wand) doesn't implement the C-API methods `MagickSetImageDispose`, or `MagickExtentImage` which is what I believe you need. Although it's fairly easy to implement those methods, you may be stuck with rebuilding each image - frame-by-frame.

```py
from wand.image import Image as Image2
from wand.color import Color
from wand.compat import nested

with nested(Image2(),
            Image2(filename='d2.gif'),
            Image2(filename='d3.gif')) as (wand, one, two):
    width = max(one.width, two.width)
    height = max(one.height, two.height)
    # Rebuild images with full extent of frame
    with Image2(width=width, height=height, background=Color('WHITE')) as f1:
        f1.composite(one, 0, 0)
        wand.sequence.append(f1)
    with Image2(width=width, height=height, background=Color('WHITE')) as f2:
        f2.composite(two, 0, 0)
        wand.sequence.append(f2)
    # Create progressive delay for each frame
    for cursor in range(2):
        with wand.sequence[cursor] as frame:
            frame.delay = 100
    wand.type = 'optimize'
    wand.save(filename='animated.gif')
```

Original answer **DO NOT USE!**

---

<strike>You want to call [`wand.image.Image.merge_layers`](https://github.com/dahlia/wand/blob/master/wand/image.py#L2294) method, not `wand.image.Image.type` property.</strike>

<strike>Try the following...</strike>

```
with Image2() as wand:
    # Add new frames into sequance
    with Image2(blob=d2) as one:
        wand.sequence.append(one)
    with Image2(blob=d3) as two:
        wand.sequence.append(two)

    # Create progressive delay for each frame
    for cursor in range(2):
        with wand.sequence[cursor] as frame:
            frame.delay = 100
    # Set layer type
    wand.merge_layers('optimize')  # or 'optimizeimage', or 'composite'
    wand.save(filename='animated.gif')
```

Comment: Thank you, but I got error using that as shown [here](https://s7.postimg.cc/vc4vdn0or/2018-05-17_16h44_18.png). I then tried all options suggested in error like merge, flatten, mosaic, but they all simply result in an image, not an animated gif.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I did not want to create a merged image (using one of methods suggested in error desc results in composite of 2 images: [here](https://s7.postimg.cc/e04irvetn/image.png)). I wanted each image to be one frame of animated gif, and animated gif taking image of largest size as its size (so it can show all images/frames).

Comment: Great. Thank you. The updated answer works (though a minor change, d2 and d3 r blobs, not files). I wish the documentation is much more elaborate on these non implemented methods. Can you also kindly look into another similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50390985/wand-creates-empty-frame-and-irregular-frame-rate) in which wand creates empty frame and irregular frame delays?